# Django Creating Using Context In Rendered View

Tags: django

I am rendering a view to an html template. I do not get any errors but the data does does not loop on the page.

I had this working but once i started using the template I have had problems. So I know it works I am just not understanding using context to render the response.

I am making a request to an api then assigning the response to a variable. Then I am creating the context based on the variable of the response. At this point I understand I should be able to access the data with the context variable.  What is the proper way of assigning a response to a a context and using the data in a template tag.

In the view

```
def github(request):
    jsonList = []
    req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/DrkSephy')
    str_response = req.content.decode('utf-8')
    jsonList.append(json.loads(str_response))
    parsedData = []
    userData = {}
    for data in jsonList:
        userData['name'] = data['name']
        userData['blog'] = data['blog']
        userData['email'] = data['email']
        userData['public_gists'] = data['public_gists']
        userData['public_repos'] = data['public_repos']
        userData['avatar_url'] = data['avatar_url']
        userData['followers'] = data['followers']
        userData['following'] = data['following']
    moviesList = parsedData.append(userData)
    context = {'moviesList': moviesList}
    return render(request, 'serviceapp/github.html', context)
```

In the html file

```
 {% for movie in moviesList %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ movie.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.blog }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.avatar_url }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.public_repos }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.public_gists }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.followers }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.following }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for moviesList in moviesList %}
```

^both the variables here are identical - you already use `moviesList` for the whole list, so you cant use it again for the variable inside loop. Use something like this:

```
{% for item in moviesList %}
    {{ item.name }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

edit:

ok, so I looked at your code again. Have you tried to print the variables in your view if they are filled correctly? Because they are not. Look at this line:

```
moviesList = parsedData.append(userData)
```

^ what you do here is you assign the result of `parsedData.append()` (which is `None`, because append is in-place modification) to the `moviesList` variable, which is then `None`.

Comment: Thank you, but yes that was just what I had right that second. I have tried key.movieslist etc. my data still does not render. Would you mind taking a look at the view. Does it appear I do have my data in moviesList?

Comment: Do I need to load the data in the view somehow before the for loop?

Comment: My goal here is to assign the data to context. Which when the problems started. Will you please show me how to do this correctly. I don't understand the concept of creating a context I guess. So what I thought I was doing was putting the response into a variable to create a context.

Comment: Meh. if I'll create the code instead of you, you wont learn anything. If your code does not work, put some `print` statements in there, so you will see where it goes wrong. Your approach is almost right, except for a few things: You have to move `userData = {}` inside the `for` loop, so the content of the variable will start empty in each loop. Then you have to move that thing `parsedData.append(userData)` inside the loop too, because you want to do append each user in the loop. And you can remove the variable `moviesList` at all, because all the data are in the variable `parsedData` already.

Comment: Thank you for that. I honestly appreciate that concern. But I dont understand. Why would this work before I render the data to a template. But it work save the data to the variable after?